# How do I fetch async data using dispatch in react js

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have write following function in react js view recordings.js

```
fetchRecordingJson(file_name)
  {

    const { dispatch, history } = this.props;
    
    if(dispatch)
    {
     
       dispatch(fetchrecordingJson(file_name));

       history.push('/app/recording-analysis');
  
    }
  

  }
```

I want to travel data coming from using function fetchrecordingJson(file_name) to another page recording-analysis

Query Is:
How do I see the data coming from function fetchrecordingJson(file_name) in recording-analysis page

I am using redux-thunk library for async calls and below is my reducer code

```
case 'RECEIVE_JSON':
            let newState = {data: action.data.data, info: action.data.info, count: state.count};
                newState.annotations = action.data.annotations.length === 0 ? [[]] :  action.data.annotations || [[]];
                newState.file_name = action.file_name;
            return Object.assign({}, newState);
```

below is my action.js code

```
export function receiveJSON(json, file_name) {
    return {
        type: RECEIVE_JSON,
        file_name,
        data: json
    }
}

    export  function fetchRecordingJson(file_name) {
    
    return dispatch => {
    
        return  axios.get(API_URL+`fetchjson/${file_name}`)
                .then(json => {
                    
                   dispatch(receiveJSON(json.data, file_name))
    
              
    
                })
       
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you using react hooks, you should use `const analysis = useSelector(state => state.<path>)`,
if it is legacy classes, use connect with `mapStateToProps`

Comment: @venkateshpogartha That is not necessarily true, you can use connect with react-hooks as well

Comment: Your code seems correct, do you get the response when you try `console.log(json)` inside `axios` call `.then` ?

Comment: @SinanYaman if you have the option to use hooks, what's the point of using connect.

Comment: @SinanYaman Yes I got the response But need to know how do I pass data  another view page Is it a good idea to use history.push method if it so how do I console that data in another page

Comment: As @venkateshpogartha said check `connect` from `react-redux` or `useSelector`, `useDispatch` hooks

Comment: @CodeTribe Try this: `dispatch(fetchrecordingJson(file_name)).then(() =>
  history.push('/app/recording-analysis')
);`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data saved in the redux store by using the [mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#:%7E:text=As%20the%20first%20argument%20passed,as%20just%20mapState%20for%20short.&text=It%20receives%20the%20entire%20store,of%20data%20this%20component%20needs.) property of redux. I have created a sample component in which we are getting the `newState` value that you have just stored in the redux store in `componentDidMount` by calling `this.props.data`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class TestOne extends Component {

    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log(this.props.data)
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
      </>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    data: state.newState
  }
}

export default connect( mapStateToProps )(TestOne)
```